# Create balanced subsets based on similarity of multiple columns

Tags: r, subset, cluster-analysis, similarity

I'm searching for a possibility to find subsets of rows (one subset should contain 6 rows), where the value-means for multiple columns are most similar. So, I would like R to search through my data.frame and **create subsets of 6 rows each, so that finally these subsets are most similar to each other**. Similarity could be measured as the Euclidean distance (as pointed out by @David Robinson).

My data looks like that:

```
  TID   Cue1  Cue2  Cue3
  1    2.06   1.90  3.82
  2    5.18   4.13  5.10
  3    5.09   2.85  2.80
  4    1.93   4.14  4.75
  ...   ...    ...   ...
```

I'd now like to know if there is a way in R, that I find the following:

-give me e.g. 4 subsets containing 6 rows eachs, whereby the 4 subsets have the **most possible similiarty in the** Cue1, Cue2 and Cue3 **means** (SD isn't important) while **each subset contains unique rows (no duplicate rows between the subsets)**.

**One example would be** (not matching the data in my example):

-**subset 1 contains** TID 1, TID 6, TID 14, TID 28, TID 39, TID 50 and this subset has the cue-means (Cue1 = 3,2; Cue2 = 2,5; Cue3 = 4)

-**subset  2 contains** TID 3, TID 12, TID 20, TID 40, TID 54, TID 59 and this subset has the cue-means (Cue1 = 3,3; Cue2 = 2,6; Cue3 = 4,1).

So that the two subsets are very (most) similar in the cue means. R should now name me the rownumbers (or the TID values) forming the subsets.

Is there any possibilty to do this in R?

**Here is an reproducible example of how my data looks like:**

```
    mysamp <- function(n, m, s, lwr, upr, nnorm) {
  set.seed(1)
  samp <- rnorm(nnorm, m, s)
  samp <- samp[samp >= lwr & samp <= upr]
  if (length(samp) >= n) {
    return(sample(samp, n))
  }  
 } 
Cue1 <- mysamp(n=60, m=3, s=1.5, lwr=1, upr=6, nnorm=1000)
Cue2 <- mysamp(n=60, m=3, s=2.5, lwr=1, upr=6, nnorm=1000)
Cue3 <- mysamp(n=60, m=4, s=1.5, lwr=1, upr=6, nnorm=1000)

df <- data.frame(TID= 1:60, Cue1= Cue1, Cue2= Cue2, Cue3= Cue3)
```

Comment: 1. What metric should one use to quantify the similarity among rows? For example, is trying to minimize the pairwise (1-2, 1-3, 1-4, 2-3, etc) Euclidean distance (sqrt of sum of squares) reasonable? 2. Can the subsets overlap? 3. Do you need a provably globally optimal solution, or would a "pretty good" one do?

Comment: For example, the following clustering approach: `distances <- dist(df[, -1]);
h <- hclust(distances); plot(h)`; gets you pretty close to finding groups of similar rows. You'd need a bit more algorithmic work to extract groups of a particular size

Comment: Thanks for the first idea! I still have difficulities applying it to my problem, as there is the particular size of 6 cases per subset. Do you have any idea how to extract groups of a particular size? As I need to do this with a bigger dataframe, I hope to find a way to calculate the subsets automatically. I need to find 12 subsets of 6 rows each, whereby a row  can only be used for only one subset.
 
I don't need the optimal solution, a pretty good one would work perfecly! And the euclidean distance is completly reasonable, yes!

Answer (score 0):

This is a clustering problem, so you'd want to approach it by:

- Calculating a distance matrix
- Using that to construct a "tree" of similar groups of nodes
- Extracting sub-clusters of your size that appear lowest on the tree

The distance matrix and hierarchical clustering can be done as:

```
distances <- dist(df[, -1])
h <- hclust(distances)
```

There are many approaches to algorithmically pulling off low clusters on the tree; since I'm accustomed to working with dplyr/purrr/tidyr I'll show one solution. This takes the approach of using `cutree` to break the tree apart at every possible level, then find the first time each group of six appears.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

clusterings <- data_frame(ncluster = seq(nrow(df), 1)) %>%
  unnest(membership = map(ncluster, ~ cutree(h, .))) %>%
  group_by(ncluster) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  nest(-ncluster, -membership) %>%
  mutate(size = map_dbl(data, nrow)) %>%
  filter(size == 6) %>%
  distinct(membership, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  unnest(data) %>%
  mutate(TID = df$TID[row])
```

On your data, this returns:

```
# A tibble: 42 × 5
   ncluster membership  size   row   TID
      <int>      <int> <dbl> <int> <int>
1        29          9     6     9     9
2        29          9     6    30    30
3        29          9     6    39    39
4        29          9     6    41    41
5        29          9     6    43    43
6        29          9     6    57    57
7        21         13     6    15    15
8        21         13     6    20    20
9        21         13     6    25    25
10       21         13     6    29    29
# ... with 32 more rows
```

Thus, (9, 30, 39, 41, 43, 57) make up your first group of 6, while the second group starts with (15, 20, 25, 29...)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately I get the following error for the data.frame "df" and for my actual one: Error in rank(x, ties.method = "first", na.last = "keep") :  argument "x" is missing, with no default.  I'm afraid I'm not able to fully understand what you do step by step with that function. Thus I don't really know how to fix the error. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again, but do you have any idea for solving the "rank( )" error in your code? Thanks a lot for your help!